# Matrices - is this matrix in reduced row echelon form?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I have a matrix: $$\begin{bmatrix}1&0&0\\0&0&0\\0&0&1\end{bmatrix}$$

Im just wondering if it is or not...

Comment: Not according to the definitions I've seen, which insist that if there are all-zero rows, they be at the bottom.

Answer (score 2):

For a matrix to be in **Reduced Row Echelon Form** it must satisfy the following conditions:

1. The first non-zero entry in any row is the number $1$. These are called pivots. This implies that every row has a $0$/$1$ pivot. Also, the first non-zero element of any non-zero row appears in the later column (furthest to the right) than the first non-zero element of the preceding row.
2. The pivot is the only non-zero entry in the column. This implies that each column can have a $0$/$1$ pivot.
3. The rows are ordered so that any rows consisting of all $0$'s are at the bottom of the matrix, i.e. all non-zero rows precede zero rows.

Since the row consisting of all zeros is **not** at the bottom of the matrix, it is **not** in reduced row echelon form. (Condition $3$ is not satisfied)